# How to make a link to a Facebook Page album be opened by the native iOS Facebook app?

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink

I'd like to create a link in my blog, so that when an iOS user clicks it, the album in my Facebook Page is opened by the native iOS Facebook app.

After searching the internet, some solutions for the native Android Facebook app are found, but I haven't found any solution for the native iOS Facebook app.

Many thanks.

Comment: you must use Facebook's universal link, which means that you just open Facebook's URL such as https://facebook.com/sdsadsdad... if app is installed on your phone, the universal link worked correctly, and iOS suggests you switch between web and app.

Comment: This is my album: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.534873094648514

What is the universal link for this album?

Comment: the link you shared is enough. it works on ios if, on your iPhone, the Facebook app is installed.

Comment: I used my friends's iPhone to open the link, but it was opened by the Safari browser, not by the Facebook app, though he has not set any default app for opening links.

Comment: plz check the right corner evil